# Unit testing and mocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, graphql, mocking

I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC and I was wondering if any one could help me with the unit testing to remove a user from the database

Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveIdAsync(string Id)
{
        try
        {
            var result = await _udService.RemoveId(Id);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (ServiceException)
        {
            return _internalServerErrorStatusCode;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test should return `asynt Task` since the subject under test is also async

Setup the mocked member to return from an async call by using `ReturnsAsync`

The subject under test makes no use of `User` class, so it is not really needed for the test

```
public async Task RemoveIdAsyncTest() {
    //Arrange               
    _mockudService //...assuming Mock<IUdService>
        .Setup(_ => _.RemoveId(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(true);

    var removeController = new RemoveController(_mockudService.Object);
    var id = "...";

    //Act
    var result = await removeController.RemoveIdAsync(id); //will return OkObjectResult

    //Assert
    OkObjectResult actual = result as OkObjectResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    Assert.IsTrue((bool)actual.Value);

    // ... assert expected behavior
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is great to see you are starting to write Unit Tests.
An example is provided in the previous answer so I will not repeat that but I will stress in learning more about unit tests.

## Unit Test

A test that verifies the behavior of some small part of the overall system.
What makes a test a unit test is that the System Under Test (SUT) is a very small subset of the overall system and may be unrecognizable to someone who is not involved in building the software. The actual SUT may be as small as a single object or method that is a consequence of one or more design decisions although its behavior may also be traced back to some aspect of the functional requirements. There is no need for unit tests to be readable, recognizable or verifiable by the customer or business domain expert.

A test is NOT a unit test if:

```
It talks to the database.
It communicates across the network.
It touches the file system.
It can’t run correctly at the same time as any of your other unit tests.
You have to do special things to your environment (such as editing config files) to run it.
```

Unit tests encourage good design and rapid feedback and they seem to help teams avoid a lot of trouble.

More info: https://codeanit.medium.com/developers-guide-write-good-test-5e3e3cdec78e

---

Furthermore, as we are using MVC framework, the rule of thumb, in MVC is `Slim Controller, Fat Model`. Having said that, you can use Repository Model for your database activities, and move your business logics to a separate classes.

Clean Code, SOLID Design Principals and following Clean Architecture would also be of some value. https://blog.ndepend.com/clean-architecture-example-part-one

And wish you all the very best!

Cheers,